# Why do different devices and OSes decode the same AAC audio differently?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, aac

Depending on the device and OS I use to view [this video](https://info.firstinspires.org/hubfs/vr%20campaign/Web/vr/videos/FIRST_360_YOUTUBE_20200302-For_The_Future_1_1_1.mp4), the stereo position of various audio elements change. For example, the piano and the person speaking at the beginning are either exclusively on the left, or are centered. Why does this happen?

Here are the results for the environments where I've tested:

- My phone running Android 9 (OxygenOS 9.0.6), Firefox, Chrome: center
- My laptop running Windows 10, Firefox, Chrome, Edge: center
- My laptop running Fedora 32, Firefox, Chrome, ffmpeg, VLC, faad: left
- Oculus Quest (Android-based), Oculus Browser or Firefox Reality: left
- Different laptop running Windows 10, Firefox, Chrome: left

I have reproduced the problem with an AAC audio file extracted from the mp4, so the issue seems to be related to the AAC decoding. As far as I can tell, the AAC audio consists of a single channel pair element with mid/side stereo coding used for some scale factor bands in some frames.

Comment: Is the codec AAC-HE, because that would explain it.

Comment: Not sure. How would I figure that out? Will something like ffprobe tell me?

Comment: ffprobe provides the following info on the audio codec:

codec_name=aac
codec_long_name=AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)
profile=LC
codec_type=audio
codec_time_base=1/44100
codec_tag_string=mp4a
codec_tag=0x6134706d